# Can Vowpal Wabbit handle datasize ~ 90 GB?

Tags: machine-learning, scalability, bigdata, logistic-regression, vowpalwabbit

We have extracted features from search engine query log data and the feature file (as per input format of Vowpal Wabbit) amounts to 90.5 GB. The reason for this huge size is necessary redundancy in our feature construction. Vowpal Wabbit claims to be able to handle TBs of data in a matter of few hours. In addition to that, VW uses a hash function which takes almost no RAM. But When we run logistic regression using VW on our data, within a few minutes, it uses up all of RAM and then stalls. 
This is the command we use-

```
vw -d train_output --power_t 1  --cache_file train.cache -f data.model 
--compressed --loss_function logistic --adaptive --invariant 
--l2 0.8e-8 --invert_hash train.model
```

train_output is the input file we want to train VW on, and train.model is the expected model obtained after training

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found the `--invert_hash` option to be extremely costly; try running without that option. You can also try turning on the `--l1` regularization option to reduce the number of coefficients in the model.

How many features do you have in your model?  How many features per row are there?

Comment: We have removed the --invert_hash option from the command and it is working fine. Training was completed within half an hour. Thanks a ton! We have a few million features in total, and there are around 15 features per row. The features have been represented keeping in the mind the sparse nature of our data.

Comment: @Satarupa Guha glad to hear that worked!  15 per row (a few million total) should pose no problem.

Comment: @Zach, I think you meant `--l1` rather than `--l2`. While both would reduce the model complexity (and thus the number of coefficients), `--l1` effect on the number of saved coefficients is much larger. I just tried a small example with about 320 features and `--l1 1` reduced the # of coeffs by about 30x while `--l2 1` reduced it only by about 0.3x - a two orders of magnitude difference.

Comment: @arielf You are correct. `l1` is lasso regularization, and `l2` is ridge regularization.  I always get them confused.

Comment: Please file a bug on `--invert_hash` at https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/issues

Comment: @smci inverting hashes is inherently costly.  If John Langford had a secret way to do that efficiently, he'd probably use it to get rich mining bitcoins rather than put it in his open source library....

Comment: @Zach I don't agree, you just store the before-and-after string and integer when hashing (subject to storage limits), then you don't need to actually invert the hash, it's just a dict lookup. All it does is use up some memory. Moreover, since the hash values are statically known (for a given set of features/interactions, and given -b bitdepth), the user could entirely workaround that memory penalty by manually storing the file of inverted-hashes (integer and corresponding string). I think JL wrote as much in one of the previous slide decks. There's nothing secret about that.

Comment: @smci The whole point of vowpal wabbit is that by hashing you limit the feature space.  If you store the entire featureset in a dictionary, you might as well skip hashing and also store the model coefficients in that dictionary.

Comment: @smci The best solution is to make a "dummy record" with the variables you want to map to their hashes.  Then predict on that dummy record with `--invert_hash`.  The prediction will be pretty fast since it's one record, and you'll get the mapping of hashes to variables for the variables you care about.